# Duda sobre versiones de mi aplicación

Tags: api, control-de-versiones, aplicación-movil

Se me plantea una duda sobre las versiones de mi aplicación. Luego de estar mirando  varias conveciones para versionar aplicaciones me decidí por un estilo parecido al de [Jet Brains](https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2016/03/09/jetbrains-toolbox-release-and-versioning-changes/) que contiene el año en que se lanzó la versión.

Dado que mi aplicación es algo sencillo, decidí que la versión tendría esta estructura:

```
YYYY.R.m
```

Donde:

- `YYYY` es el año en que se lanzó la versión
- `R` es el número de la versión (mayor), partiendo de `1`
- `m` es el número de la versión (menor), partiendo de `1`

Este sería el historial de versiones hasta ahora:

- `2018.1`
- `2019.1`
- `2019.1.1`
- `2019.2`

Significa que en `2018` hubo una sola versión mayor, nada más. Mientras que en `2019`hubieron dos versiones mayores. Y, de la versión `1` de `2019` se lanzó también una versión menor que corregía algunos errores.

## El problema

Mi problema ahora es que a finales de diciembre lancé la versión `2019.2` (segunda versión mayor de la aplicación lanzada en 2019). Ahora estamos en `2020` pero he encontrado algunos fallos menores  en la versión `2019.2` y quisiera corregirlos. Son realmente fallos menores, no hay que hacer cambios profundos por ejemplo a nivel de la API que trabaja con la aplicación y a la que se accede también usando rutas parecidas a la versión, por ejemplo, la ruta actual de la API es `2019/2/recurso/...` Es algo que he procurado también para no hacerme un lío: que las rutas de la API correspondan con la versión mayor actual.

Entonces, si hago esas pequeñas correcciones y lanzo una versión menor, ésta debería llamarse `2019.2.1`, pero estamos en `2020`.

¿Sería correcto hacer eso? ¿Conocen algún estándar de versiones en el que se maneje este tipo de situaciones: versionado basado en el año y actualizaciones lanzadas en años posteriores a la salida de la versión principal?

Comment: El uso de semantic version pudiera ser una opción viable para tu desarrollo como me parece demasiado extensa su explicación y no deseo omitir nada te dejo el enlace https://semver.org/

Comment: Gracias @Aprendiz. Eso es lo que yo aplico (más o menos), con la diferencia de que me gustó lo del año y en lugar de poner versión `1,2,3...` decidí versionar con el año de lanzamiento y el dilema está precisamente en lanzar una versión menor en 2020 de una versión mayor de 2019.